# can convert an array of arrays to an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, google-apps-script

I want to convert an array of arrays to an object array.

How can I convert this:

```
[["123456","Maria","M"],["589657","Padre","F"],["896555","Jose","M"],]
```

...to this?

```
[{Id:"123456", Nombre:"Maria", Sexo:"M"},{Id:"589657", Nombre:"Padre", Sexo:"F"},{Id:"896555", Nombre:"Jose",  Sexo:"M"},]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let arr = [["123456","Maria","M"],["589657","Padre","F"],["896555","Jose","M"]];
let res = arr.map(([Id, Nombre, Sexo]) => ({Id, Nombre, Sexo}));
console.log(res);
```